# Xamarin forms navigate to modal page from navigation page

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm having trouble with navigating to a modal page.
My MainPage in App() is set to a NavigationPage like so:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new StartPage());
```

I'm trying to push a new page onto the stack from the StartPage like this:

```
public async void DisplayAdd()
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AddGameModalPage());
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying that it's not compatible with the Xamarin.Forms.Page.

I've also tried something like this, but the error still remains.

```
var page = new NavigationPage(new AddGameModalPage());
Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
```

Comment: Post details about the error, and what is AddGameModalPage?

Comment: *I'm getting an error* - Runtime error, compile-time error? What? You'll need to give some more details.